# JDialog not showing up

Tags: java, eclipse, jbutton, jdialog

I have this code for JDialog:

```
public void createUI() {

    contentPane2 = new JPanel();
    contentPane2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    contentPane2.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("menu"));
    contentPane2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane2);

    contentPane2.setLayout(new FormLayout(new ColumnSpec[] {
            ColumnSpec.decode("149px"),
            ColumnSpec.decode("max(38dlu;default):grow"),
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            ColumnSpec.decode("max(48dlu;default)"),
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            ColumnSpec.decode("46px:grow"),
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,},
        new RowSpec[] {
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            RowSpec.decode("max(20dlu;default)"),
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            RowSpec.decode("14px"),
            FormFactory.UNRELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,}));

    JLabel lblAddNewTask = new JLabel("PLEASE FILL THE NEW TASK INFORMATION", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblAddNewTask.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblAddNewTask.setToolTipText("");
    lblAddNewTask.setOpaque(true);
    lblAddNewTask.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    lblAddNewTask.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblAddNewTask.setBorder(new TitledBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TitledBorder.border"), "", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, Color.YELLOW));
    lblAddNewTask.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    lblAddNewTask.setAlignmentX(0.5f);
    contentPane2.add(lblAddNewTask, "1, 2, 8, 1, fill, fill");

    JLabel lblChooseActivity = new JLabel("CHOOSE ACTIVITY :");
    contentPane2.add(lblChooseActivity, "1, 6, center, default");

    final JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox();
    comboBox_1.addItem("Diagnosis");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Treatment");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Medication");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Rehab");
    comboBox_1.addItem("Discharge");
    contentPane2.add(comboBox_1, "2, 6, left, default");

    JLabel lblName = new JLabel("NEW TASK NAME :");
    contentPane2.add(lblName, "1, 10, center, default");

    textField = new JTextField();
    contentPane2.add(textField, "2, 10, fill, default");
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblDay = new JLabel("DAY :");
    contentPane2.add(lblDay, "1, 14, center, default");

    final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.addItem("1");
    comboBox.addItem("2");
    comboBox.addItem("3");      
    contentPane2.add(comboBox, "2, 14, left, default");

    final JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Complication");
    contentPane2.add(chckbxNewCheckBox, "2, 18");

    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("ADD");
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            System.out.println(comboBox_1.getSelectedItem());   //getActivity
            //System.out.println(textField.getText());   //getTaskName
             if (chckbxNewCheckBox.isSelected()){//if complication
                System.out.println("*"+textField.getText());//setTaskName have * sign

                JButton btn_6222 = new JButton("BAKAR BAKAR");
             //   btn_6222.addActionListener(deleteAction);
                BigPanel.add(btn_6222, "4, 3");
                BigPanel.updateUI();


                }
            else{
                System.out.println(textField.getText());    
                }
            System.out.println(comboBox.getSelectedItem());  //getDay
            //System.out.println(chckbxNewCheckBox.getText());//getCheckedItem

              String filename = "c:" + File.separator + "Text File from addCHECKUP Class.txt";
                File f = new File(filename);
                PrintWriter pw = null;
                try {

                    pw = new PrintWriter(f);                
                    pw.println(comboBox_1.getSelectedItem());
                    if (chckbxNewCheckBox.isSelected()){//if complication
                        pw.println("*"+textField.getText());

                        }
                    else{
                        pw.println(textField.getText());

                        }
                    pw.println(comboBox.getSelectedItem());
                    pw.flush();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    //no matter what happen. close the output stream always.
                    //note that closing a printer will not throw IOException
                    if(pw!=null){
                        pw.close();
                    }


            }






            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Successfully added !");
        }


    });
    contentPane2.add(btnAdd, "8, 20");

        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setTitle("Add New Task");
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setBounds(470, 180, 534, 323);
        dialog.add(contentPane2);
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

This code is for actionPerformed of a button. When this button is clicked, it will show JDialog createUI() above

```
JButton button_3 = new JButton("ADD");//ADD ROW
    button_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             createUI();

        }

    });
```

The problem is when I click the button, JDialog not showing up. I try to figure out what's wrong with the code but could not find it. Please someone look at the possible solution. Thanks

Comment: Where is this `JDialog`, at the start of `createGUI` function or at the end of it. Why you adding `contentPane2` to two different containers, one at the start of `createGUI` and one at the end?

Comment: do you get any error ?if so add it to the post

Comment: Coild you post a short simplified code to demonstrate the problem ?

Comment: @nIcEcOw Thank you Sir! I should change contentPane2 to contentPane and delete  setContentPane(contentPane2);

Answer (score 2):

try calling

```
dialog.pack();
```

before setting it visible.

Comment: i don't think that's not the reason for not visible